# Ubuntu 17.10 - Poweroff operation is inhibited by myself

Tags: command-line, 17.10, shutdown

When I find myself in a terminal and want to shut down my computer, I will often use the poweroff command. This has always worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. However, on Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit, I am getting this message:

```
aaronfranke@ub17vm:~$ poweroff
Operation inhibited by "aaronfranke" (PID 951 "gnome-session-b", user aaronfranke), reason is "user session inhibited".
Please retry operation after closing inhibitors and logging out other users.
Alternatively, ignore inhibitors and users with 'systemctl poweroff -i'.
```

I know that I can work around the issue using the suggested command, but I want to know, why is this happening? Is there an issue that can be fixed? Should I bother to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar messages can appear when you type `reboot` in the command line. The solution is to use `sudo reboot` instead. In your case it would be `sudo poweroff` or `sudo shutdown` which does the same thing. Always make sure you have saved all your work and closed down Libre Office, etc.

The other solution for me is to pick **Reboot** from the system menu. In this case the `sudo` isn't necessary. In you case you would pick **Shutdown** from the system menu.

Lastly, you can do as the message suggests and use:

```
systemctl poweroff -i
```

Comment: This doesn't really explain why the problem happens, but these are good solutions.

Comment: If you use any of these options described above you can restart/shutdown the computer but the shutdown/reboot process is really slow because it waits for these inhibitors to close for something like 90 seconds each.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue in 20.04 . In my case the Caffeine Gnome extension was the inhibitor.  I turned it off and now reboot and poweroff work without `sudo`. Hope this helps.

Comment: this worked in 18.04

Answer (score 0):

You maybe running some program in the background that prevents normal reboot to happen.
for example:-
if you are running a software in gnome-tweaks that prevents auto suspend and screensaver, you will get that message until you disable that.

Now, in your case i don't know which program preventing it, for a good measure try to see if there is an startup program that you added or a program that you started manually that runs till your shutdown.